# Conditional @OnetoMany relationship in Ebean

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, one-to-many, ebean

I have a `parent` entity which has a `OneToMany` relationship with a `child` entity.

I'd like to define a conditional relationship between these where `child` has an `attribute` column field with a value of 3. `attribute` is an integer column in `child` table like so in the model:

```
@Constraints.Required
@NotNull
protected Integer attribute;
```

Here is what I tried in the `parent` entity class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@Where(clause = "attribute = 3")
List<Child> specificChildren;
```

However the generated query ignores the where clause I made, and gives me all children relating to that parent, not just the ones with `attribute = 3`. Changing the `clause` to `${ta}.attribute = 3` was also unsuccessful.

Here is the SQL generated `query.getGeneratedSql()`:

```
select distinct on (t1.attribute, t0.id) t0.id, t1.attribute
from parent t0
left join child t1 on t1.parent_id = t0.id
order by t1.someotherattribute
```

The `@Where` attribute is being ignored completely, as no matter what I do with it, the generated SQL is not affected.

There is a `io.ebean.annotation.Where` class, so it seems like it should be able to work, but I haven't found any Ebean specific documentation on it (Ebean's docs do seem to be somewhat lacking). Most information I find about the `@Where` annotation relates to Hibernate. I did find the source code for it [here](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean-annotation/blob/master/src/main/java/io/ebean/annotation/Where.java) though.

Is this supported in this way? Or is there another method this could be accomplished?

I'm currently using PostgreSQL 10.4, Ebean 10.4.4, Play 2.6.7, using Play's Ebean plugin 4.0.6. I tried updating to Play's Ebean 4.1.3 with no success. Not sure if the versions I am using are to blame or not.

More information found in a Google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ebean/N0j2KhIIGR4).

Comment: Is `attribute` the exact column name in the database as well as being the name of the mapped field on the `Child` entity?

Comment: @SteveChambers That's correct. Updated post with how it is defined in the `Child`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on my end, so let me please:

1. Firstly describe how it looks on my side
2. Then provide an assumption about the issue on your side
3. And then to ask some clarification questions (in case further help will be needed)

---

### Working solution

I've used *Ebean 10.4.4* and *PostgreSQL 10* (works for *MySQL 6.7* too).

1. Main part from the *Employee* class, it is a `child` entity:

   ```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
   private Department department;

   protected int attribute;
   ```
2. Main part from the *Department* class, it is a `parent` entity:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
   @Where(clause = "attribute = 3")
   private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   ```
3. Find query

   ```
   Query<Department> query = Ebean.find(Department.class).fetch("employees")
           .where().eq("name", "DevOps").query();
   Department department = query.findUnique();
   String queryString = query.getGeneratedSql();
   System.out.println(queryString);
   ```

   Important part here is eagerly fetching `"employees"` field. Result output looks like this:

   ```
   select t0.id, t0.name, t1.id, t1.name, t1.attribute_test, t1.department_id
   from department t0
   left join employee t1 on t1.department_id = t0.id
   where attribute_test = 3 and t0.name = ?
   order by t0.id
   ```

---

### Assumption

Main assumption (since I don't know how you've queried/searched the entity) is that you didn't fetched eagerly `child` entities and they were fetched using separate SQL.

E.g. in my example above if I will remove `.fetch("employees")` part and will do so:

```
Query<Department> query = Ebean.find(Department.class)
        .where().eq("name", "DevOps").query();
Department department = query.findUnique();
String queryString = query.getGeneratedSql();
System.out.println(queryString);
System.out.println(department); // uses this.employees in #toString() - so will lazily fetch child entities
```

I will have:

- The output below for the `queryString`:

  ```
  select t0.id, t0.name from department t0 where t0.name = ?
  ```
- Next output for the `department` (I have two employees in the department with `attribute = 2` and one with `attribute = 3`):

  ```
  Department [
    id=1,
    name=java,
    employees=[{Employee [id=3, name=Batman, attribute=3, department=DevOps]}]
  ]
  ```
- And 2 SQL queries in the logs (utilized *Logback* here), one to find department, another to fetch employees (with `@Where` related logic):

  ```
  08:09:35.038 [main] DEBUG io.ebean.SQL - txn[1001] select t0.id, t0.name from department t0 where t0.name = ? ; --bind(java)
  08:09:35.064 [main] DEBUG io.ebean.SQL - txn[1002] select t0.department_id, t0.id, t0.name, t0.attribute_test, t0.department_id from employee t0 where attribute_test = 3 and (t0.department_id) in (?) ; --bind(1)
  ```

---

### Clarification questions

In case things described above will not work, could you please provide next information:

1. Which version of PostgreSQL is using?
2. Is `@ManyToOne` used on the `child` entity side?
3. Could you please provide logs for the SQL queries initiated by your program?

   It will be enough to enable *Logback* for this like it is described [here >>](https://www.baeldung.com/logback): just need to add dependencies and to utilize [this >>](https://github.com/ebean-orm-examples/example-minimal/blob/master/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml) configuration file.

Comment: This seems to have fixed most of my issues, the `@Where` clause is certainly being used now given the fetch in the query. Before I had posted this, I had tried making my One to Many annotation the following: `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")`. Would this not do the same thing? (I think I may have read somewhere that it isn't supported in Play's Ebean, not sure if that's true or not.)

Comment: My one other issue was that if `.fetch("child")` was added, any orderBy expression I added to the query would not be respected as the generated sql would add `ORDER BY t0.id` (with t0 being the parent table). I fixed this by making the fetch statement `.fetch("child", new FetchConfig().query())` This split it into two queries, but still joined everything up in the end. Would this be the correct way to do this?

Comment: @DavisMariotti, which way is used for `ORDER BY` on your side? If you will do `Ebean.find(Department.class).fetch("employees").orderBy("attribute").where().eq("name", "java").query();` it will fetch and order within one query, can you try it please? What relates to `FetchConfig`` - it's purpose is to do fetch in a separate query, so it is a possibility, but I would prefer 1 query instead by myself.

Comment: @DavisMariotti, _Ebean_ supports JPA only partially, correct. `FetchType.EAGER` was not supported for `@ManyToMany` couple years ago for sure. What relates to `@OneToMany` and `FetchType.EAGER` - it didn't not work on my side yesterday without a `fetch` too.

Comment: Not sure what made this the case, but once I implemented this into my actual code (instead of a test I made), that ordering issue went away and everything worked fine. Now however, if I use `setFirstRow()` and `setMaxRows` on the query, it splits them up into two queries, which is actually breaking the ordering. If I remove those two expressions, the query is created as one sql query and the ordering works fine.

Comment: @DavisMariotti, could you please provide your full query? If you don't mind, I will be glad if you will mark my answer as a correct one since it covers the original question.

Comment: I've taken the logs and the query and pasted them [here](https://hastebin.com/urecahajin.sql)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180558/discussion-between-davis-mariotti-and-marme1ad).